# Get an value from dynamically generated array

Tags: php, get, key-value-store

I have an array as this

Array
(
    [13802172] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13802172
            [1] => reviewed
            [2] => ACCESS HIRE NSW
            [3] => ACCESS HIRE NSW PTY LTD
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => EQUIP RENTALS & LEASING SERVICES, TOOL R
            [7] => 5106206
            [8] => 
            [9] => 7394
        )

```
[13802174] => Array
    (
        [0] => 13802174
        [1] => reviewed
        [2] => ACRON ROAD OSHC
        [3] => ACRON ROAD OUT OF SCHOOL
        [4] => 
        [5] => 
        [6] => CHILD CARE SERVICES
        [7] => 5122005
        [8] => 
        [9] => 8351
    )
```

)

Where the 13802174 and 13802172 are generated dynamically through the script.

Now I need the value of [13802172][6] as EQUIP RENTALS & LEASING SERVICES, TOOL R dynamically, the array keys can be many and I need to display all keys of 6th index value..

Can you guys please suggest me an answer how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just loop through the entire array and then ask for the 7th value(index 6):

```
foreach($arr as $v) 
  printf("<pre>%s</pre>", $v[6]);
```

You can also have a look at `array_keys`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you will have many arrays like this

```
[13802174] => Array
    (
        [0] => 13802174
        [1] => reviewed
        [2] => ACRON ROAD OSHC
        [3] => ACRON ROAD OUT OF SCHOOL
        [4] => 
        [5] => 
        [6] => CHILD CARE SERVICES
        [7] => 5122005
        [8] => 
        [9] => 8351
    )
```

I assume you have assigned each of then to an array of dynamically generated arrays.

You can loop this way

```
foreach($dynamicallyGeneratedArrays as $key => $dynamicArray) {

    print $key.": ".$dynamicArray[6];
}
```

Or you might want to assign it to a new array

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($dynamicallyGeneratedArrays as $key => $dynamicArray) {

    if(isset($dynamicArray[6]) {

        $newArray[$key] = $dynamicArray[6];
    }
}
```

If you need anything else to achive the result you want, comment so I try to help editing my answer